# How do I push website content down and insert ad at the top?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Can someone tell me how to write code that pushes the content of a finished webpage down half an inch or so, then loads an ad across the top of the page, like this example:

http://abcnews.go.com/International/hideouts-sacred-spaces-experts-baffled-mysterious-underground-chambers/story?id=14136379

(example may no longer be showing this ad/function)

The entire page loads, then gets pushed down, then the ad loads at the top of the page.  My code for this would be at/near the bottom of my clients html.

The ad content will come from a different server.

The same code would ideally work with all/most finished websites instead of being specifically tailored for each one.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: You would need Javascript (jQuery) to do this. It cannot be done server-side.

Comment: @Evan: Javascript != jQuery. This can be achieved without jQuery or any other js lib.

Comment: @RichardH jQuery would make it a lot easier. But I don't know why he really wants .... Most (if not all) ads are randomized by the ad-server, you shouldn't take care of that yourself (I'm pretty sure you aren't even able to do so) ...

Comment: @Richard H: I was simply suggesting jQuery for the reason Tim stated above.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you implement your ads in your HTML by using a static code (eg. when you're using Google Ads). When you put this code on top of your page, it'll show the ad on top of your page. Optionally, you can style it a bit so it's centered.

Since you load your ads from a different server, I don't see any reason why the HTML-code behind those ads is dynamic (I don't know if it is?). Your ad-provider will take care of showing the ads in a random-order.

Comment: It does not have to be PHP/dynamic, I just thought that would be necessary and/or be more likely to always work without being blocked, or having to be "enabled" etc.  This code will be added to the bottom of my clients' html, that is why I believe the page will load first, then get pushed down by my code, and then display the ad.

Comment: Oh, I see. You think that (since ads load pretty slow) those will block the rest of your page (until they're loaded, which can take quite a time)?

Comment: If that's what you mean, you can just add the `async='async'` attribute to your ad-`<script ...>` so it'll load in the background and won't block the rest of your page :)!

Comment: Tim, and @Evan, thanks for your help.  Maybe it will help to imagine that there are ten web pages that don't belong to me.  They will allow me to run my ad at the top of their pages.  They agree to put my code on their pages to accomplish this, but each one will put my code in a different place in their html (most likely toward the bottom). In addition, they want all of my code to be in one "chunk" -all together in the same place in their html - lines 450 through 570, for instance, but nowhere else. So I cannot put anything anywhere else, i.e. "just after the body tag".

Comment: Tim, Evan, @Richard: It is OK for the pages to load as normal, and display my ad whenever it gets to my chunk of code (whether my code is in the middle of the html or at the bottom of it).  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd looked at the source of the page you'd see this this is achieved using JavaScript, not PHP. If you want it to happen (seemingly) after the page loads you need to write some php to inculde the html/JavaScript/images whatever for the ad, then some JavaScript to dispay it once the page has finished loading. Or use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to dynamically modify the DOM.

Check out the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) JavaScript framework.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use a front-end code like jquery or normal javascript, and prepend your ad to the body.

OR

If you want to do it with a server-side language. You can add the server variable just after the opening body tag, and populate the html to the variable via server-side code.

See my example:

Gray : body tag
Green : your website
Red : the ad section

If you don't have a wrapper container around your div, add one. And use the methods I mentioned above to prepend the ad to your site.

[image: HTML Example]